# Can't get clear all checked boxes in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have tried this a few different ways but can't get code to uncheck or clear all check boxes after all boxes have been selected. Latest code looks like...

```
$(".select_all").click(function(){
    var state = ($(this).html() == "Select All") ? true : false;    
    $(this).html((state) ? "Clear" : "Select All");

    if ($(':checked').prop('checked', false)) {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
         this.checked = true;                      
        });
    } else {
        $(':checkbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = false;                      
        });                                      
    };                                           
})
```

Comment: What about showing some HTML? Not sure what your state checks are for.

Comment: If you just want to uncheck all check boxes you could do `$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've undestood right, you need something like this. Check the snippet below or this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdschgyy/).

```js
$(".select_all").click(function(){
  var state = $(this).html() == "Select All";
  $(this).html((state) ? "Clear" : "Select All");

  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', state);        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">

<a href="#" class="select_all">Select All</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the possible HTML, the select_all element could be a checkbox or a button or other. I assumed you are in one of the first two possibilities.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select_all").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var state = ( $(this).html() == "Select All") ? true : false;
    $(this).html((state) ? "Clear" : "Select All");
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', state);
  });
  
  $(".select_all1").click(function(e){
    var state = ( this.nextSibling.textContent == "Select All") ? true : false;
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', state);
    this.nextSibling.textContent = (state) ? "Clear" : "Select All";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<form action="demo.asp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> I have a car<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select_all1" name="selectAll" value="selectAll">Select All<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <button class="select_all">Select All</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(':checked').prop('checked', false)` **sets** the property to `false` on every checked box. It doesn't return `true/false`, so it can't be used as the condition in `if`. If you want to test whether there are no checked boxes, use:

```
if ($(':checked').length == 0)
```

Then to check all the boxes, you can do:

```
$(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

But there isn't really any need to do this check at all; you already determined whether it's select all or clear in the `state` variable at the top of the function.

You don't need to use `.each()` -- all the jQuery functions that modify the DOM loop automatically when the selector matches multiple elements.

And it's rarely necessary to use `? true : false` in a ternary -- you can simply use the expression before that as the boolean value.

So the full code is:

```
$(".select_all").click(function(){
    var state = $(this).text() == "Select All";    
    $(this).text(state ? "Clear" : "Select All");
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', !state);                               
});
```